# Algolia Grouping (attributeForDistinct)

Tags: grouping, distinct, algolia

I'm grouping data by the attributeForDistinct option from Algolia dashboard. Is there any way to use this option from react-instantSearch-dom? There is a distinct option in the dashboard that can be changed from code true/false. I want to use the attributeForDistinct option from code to group data dynamically.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzdiu.png)

Answer (score 0):

You would turn on `distinct` in your index configuration, or you can configure it client side by adding it to a `Configure` widget.

Here's a simple example:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/configure/react/#examples

Set it to an integer value between 0 and 4 to control the number of records with the same value for `attributeForDistinct` returned in the result set.

Comment: I want to control attributeForDistinct from client side. Is there a way to control it?